# Animation feature to directions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, ng-map

I need to display google map with directions.Also I want to change directions with an animation.I referd the following example.

[Plunker Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/Dmjr25l6qQelDtbd3U3F?p=preview)

```
<ng-map zoom="14" center="37.7699298, -122.4469157" style="height:90%" on-click="logLatLng()">
    <directions draggable="true" panel="directions-panel" travel-mode="{{travelMode}}" waypoints="{{wayPoints}}" origin="{{origin}}" destination="{{destination}}">
    </directions>
</ng-map>
```

How to add animation feature to directions when ever a location changes?